# Symfony2 1:M Post:Comment situation. How do I pass parent Post obj to child Comment view/form

Tags: symfony

a Symfony2 newbie question.

Say I have a 1:M Post:Comment situation.

Within the Show view for a single Post, I want to have a  New form to create a Comment, clearly a Comment of the shown Post.

Doing things almost by default, I get a New form with a select whose options are all the Post (note: the shown Post is indeed the selected option), which is Ok but not so good.

I am unable to define a New form with a hidden field whose value is somehow the shown Post, or its Id.

Does Symfony2 require to use data transformer even for such basic task?
Help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a comment-route which has the parent post's id as url parameter like this:

```
POST: http://localhost/post/123/comment   (creates a comment for post 123)
```

Your `routing.yml` could look like this:

```
acme_post_create_comment:
   path: /post/{post_id}/comment
   requirements: { post_id: "\d+" }
   methods: "POST"
   defaults: { _controller: ... }
```

Depending on how you create your form, you have to specify this route and the parent post as the form's action (see Symfony docs on Form for details).

Your Controller could look like this:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function createCommentAction(Request $request, $post_id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $post = $em->getrepository('AcmeBlogBundle:Post')->find($post_id);
        if (!$post) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('post not found');
        }
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->setPost($post);
        $form = $this->createForm(new CommentForm(), $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Persist comment and redirect to post
        }
        // Display comment form with errors
    }
```

Comment: thks. You suggest this to avoid Data Trasf., don't you? If so, are you sure it fixes my issue (on select)?

Comment: You don't have a select in this case and why would you? You want to write a comment on a post, not write a comment and then _select_ which post it belongs to. So a hidden field is a better choice. Having your post be submitted as part of the url makes it clear where the comment belongs to and is more RESTful, but both choices are ok.

Answer (score 0):

The following with Data Transformer works, and it is decently straightforward.
It is almost as from the documentation example http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

```
<?php
 /* src/Mario/Bundle/BlogBundleForm/DataTransformer/PostToIdTransformer.php */
namespace Mario\Bundle\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Mario\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Issue;

class PostToIdTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
/**
 * @var ObjectManager
 */
private $om;

/**
 * @param ObjectManager $om
 */
public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
{
    $this->om = $om;
}

/**
 * Transforms an object (post) to a string (id).
 *
 * @param  Post|null $post
 * @return string
 */
public function transform($post)
{
    if (null === $post) {
        return "";
    }

    return $post->getId();
}

/**
 * Transforms a string (id) to an object (post).
 *
 * @param  string $id
 *
 * @return Post|null
 *
 * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (post) is not found.
 */
public function reverseTransform($id)
{
    if (!$id) {
        return null;
    }

    $post = $this->om
        ->getRepository('MarioBlogBundle:Post')
        ->findOneBy(array('id' => $id))
    ;

    if (null === $post) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
            'An post with id "%s" does not exist!',
            $id
        ));
    }

    return $post;
}
}
?>
```

Then within my CommentType, I define

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $entityManager = $options['em'];
    $transformer = new PostToIdTransformer($entityManager);
    $builder
        ->add('author')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('comment')
        ->add(
        $builder->create('post', 'hidden')
            ->addModelTransformer($transformer));
}
```

I also need to pass $em, within the CommentController definition of the createForm

```
/**
* Creates a form to create a Comment entity.
*
* @param Comment $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createCreateForm(Comment $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('Mario_Comment_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ));
    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Scrivi commento'));
    return $form;
}
```

So, it is easy. Thks Cheers

(Comment: I would say that, for M:1 relationship, by default Symfony2 should have a New form for a child obj with (hidden) value for just the (unique) parent obj. Symfony2 indeed knows that value.)